# How to conditionally include code only if above certain iOS version?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a piece of code that only works on iOS 6 or greater.

```
control.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Is there a ready to use compiler directive like `#ifdef iOS6_or_greater`?

Comment: Have you thought about your question?  Conditional compilation produces a binary depending on different things (perhaps the deployment target) but that binary will do the same thing regardless.  You need to provide runtime checks, not compile-time checks.

Answer (score 17):

It's best if you check against the functionality, instead of the iOS version.

For example you can use respondsToSelector to see if a given method is supported.

```
[someObject respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]
```

Failing that, there is a preprocessor directive

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 60000
- (BOOL)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
#endif
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `tintColor` was added to `UIView` in iOS 7. OP should be using `respondsToSelector:` instead of using version number checks.

Comment: In my screwed up case I needed the #if compiler directive because I have to do my ios7 compiles on a macbook with xcode 5 but all my day to day work needs to be compiled on an older mac pro that doesn't support 10.8 and therefore doesnt support xcode 5. All my other tools, psd, etc are on the mac pro.  So I have to take the code back and forth between the two.  The above compiler directive makes it easy and will help me not to forget to uncomment out the ios7 code at the end.  So thanks for listing both! +1

Comment: Answer says "it's best" and @MikeWeller says it's "the correct answer." Any reason why? Personally, I prefer the version checks because you can remove them later, and they are all the same.

Comment: Well, usually if you check for a selector and it's there and the code executes, everything is ok. If for example you use a version check of > 6.0 and they remove the selector in iOS 8, then you're going to crash, hence the why it's the better approach. In one of the earlier WWDC videos, they mentioned that this is actually part of the reason why when the iPad launched, it was supporting "most" iPhone apps and not all.

Comment: I had to resort to version number checking to support both watchOS1 and watchOS2 since Apple removed `-[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:reply:]` in watchOS2 outright. I had to use the version check to conditionally compile out the legacy method in my API's implementation so that it would work in both my watchOS1 and watchOS2 app targets.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for this...........

```
float currSysVerFloat = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]floatValue];
if (currSysVerFloat>=6.0) {
    isversion6=TRUE;
    control.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    //This is iOS6 or greater
} else {
    //do nothing
    isversion6 = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to check for the existence of a new selector. You should almost never need to check the system version. Use `respondsToSelector:` instead.

Comment: @MikeWeller If `control` happens to be a `UIButton` that might be not what you want. `UIButton` has a `tintColor` since iOS 5.0, `UISegmentedControl` even since 2.0, yet other controls don't. Coloring only buttons seems stupid, so checking the OS version *could* be the right thing to do.

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone that tries to use this in watchOS: UIDevice does not exist in the watchOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I just give you basic code of compare system version

Write following code in

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

your `projectName-Prefix.pch` so you can access it in anywhere you want .

And apply it as condition such like

```
if( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6") )
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone that tries to use this in watchOS: `UIDevice` does not exist in the watchOS SDK.